# Project - Configuration type utility for C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

Using CMake 3.13 to generate Visual Studio 2017 C++ project will produce a solution that includes "INSTALL" and "ZERO_CHECK" and "ALL_BUILD" projects. All these projects use Configuration Type "Utility" which does not compile code but shall "Displays utility toolset (MIDL, custom build, prebuild, postbuild events)".

Does Visual Studio 2017 provide a similar project type for a pure C# solution? In this scenario the developers do not have C++ package installed on their VS2017.

Comment: Would it be possible to instead configure your executables/assemblies to not require database and registry updates?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But the thing you are asking for assistance is not to solve a programming, an algorithm or a pattern issue with some code. To help you improve your requests, please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: Question has been updated. Can you please re-open?